# How does `man git init` get the right man page?

Tags: man

So it seems that typing `man git init` into a bash prompt on an Ubuntu 14.04 system does the same as `man git-init`, only I'm not quite sure how.

The `man` page for `man` (i.e. `man man`) doesn't seem to allow for this construct, unless `git` was a `section` of the manual, but the man page seems to come from section `1`.

Is this an undocumented usage supported by `man`?  Have I misunderstood the documentation of `man`?  Is some other magic happening?   Anyone care to explain?

Comment: Appears as though git-init may just be a wrapper for `git init`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Some implementations of `man`, including the one used by Ubuntu, replace spaces in its search terms with hyphens and attempt to find a manual page under that name. So `man git init` looks for the same thing as `man git-init`. Similarly, `man run parts` and `man ntfs 3g` work (if you have `run-parts` and `ntfs-3g` on your system).

It only does this with word pairs, though, so `man git annex sync` does not work (though `man git-annex sync` does, as that's again a word pair).

In fact, when you ask for two manual pages (e.g., `man git bash` to see both the git and bash manpages), `man` actually first tries to look for a `git-bash` manpage. You can see this in the debug output if you enable it with `-d`.

This man feature is called "subpages" you can read the [source code implementing subpages in man-db](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/tree/src/man.c?id=97fcf427108bc61305accb1eb252eb18acca224c#n4245) (thanks, [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt)). Searching the [`man(1)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) for "subpages" will also lead you to the description of this behavior under the `--no-subpages` option:

```
--no-subpages
      By default, man will try to interpret pairs of manual page
      names given on the command line as equivalent to a single
      manual page name containing a hyphen or an underscore.  This
      supports the common pattern of programs that implement a
      number of subcommands, allowing them to provide manual pages
      for each that can be accessed using similar syntax as would be
      used to invoke the subcommands themselves.  For example:

        $ man -aw git diff
        /usr/share/man/man1/git-diff.1.gz

      To disable this behaviour, use the --no-subpages option.

        $ man -aw --no-subpages git diff
        /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz
        /usr/share/man/man3/Git.3pm.gz
        /usr/share/man/man1/diff.1.gz
```

Comment: This seems to not work on CentOS 6.6.  Is it Ubuntu only?

Comment: @Wildcard which part seems to not work? It should work as long as CentOS is using [man-db](http://man-db.nongnu.org/) (there are other `man` implementations), and subpages haven't been disabled (e.g., with `--no-subpages`). I'm using Debian, so it definitely isn't just Ubuntu.

Comment: The important thing is that this is unique to a *specific* implementation of `man`. It is by no means universal or particular common.